# Model relationship to html template

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I've been struggling for this issue for a few hours - I know there's probably a simple solution that I'm overlooking.

I have a one to many relationship with my models.

I have need to return all rows of one object with the rows for the related object.

In a sense I have this:

```
 object 
 object
   object_relationship.property
   object_relationship.property
object
   object_relationship.property
object
```

Now - I can run through all of these fine, but I run into an issue when I want to send these back to the html template.

I can send the object back - but how do I send the object_relationship back in the order that I have it above?

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2):

You might not need to worry too much about this, acutally... look at these models:

```
class Venue(base.NamedEntity, HasPerformances, HasUrl, HasLocation):
    city = db.ReferenceProperty(City, collection_name='venues')
    url = db.StringProperty(required=True, validator=validators.validate_url)
    location = db.GeoPtProperty()

class Performance(base.Entity):
    show = db.ReferenceProperty(Show, collection_name='performances', required=True)
    utc_date_time = db.DateTimeProperty(required=True)
    venue = db.ReferenceProperty(Venue, collection_name='performances', required=True)
```

In a case like this, nothing stops you from using `venue.performances` from either code or templates and treating it as a list. The API will automatically fire queries as needed to fetch the actual objects. The same thing goes for `performance.venue`.

The only problem here is performance - you've got a variant of the [n+1 problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem) to deal with. There are workarounds, though, like [this article](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/01/ReferenceProperty-prefetching-in-App-Engine) by Nick Johnson. I'd suggest reading the API code too... it makes for interesting reading how the property get is captured and dereferenced.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is to denormalize the data if you are going to do many reports like that.  For example, maybe you could include `object.name` on the `object_relationship` entity.

That said, you could send a list of dicts to your template, so maybe something like:

```
data = []
for entity in your_query:
   children = [{'name': child.name} for child in entity.object_relation]
   data.append({'name': object.name,
                'children': children,
                 ...
               })
```

Then pass the `data` list to your template, and process it.

Please note, this will perform very badly.  It will execute another query for *every* one of the items in your first query.  Use [Appstats](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats.html) to profile your app.

Comment: Thanks Robert - that did the trick - I agree on the performance, we may need to denormalize this one soon.